# Outlook add-in Graph API SSO support on mobile

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I have an Outlook web add-in that supports mobile devices and uses the Outlook REST API to perform operations that office-js does not offer e.g. moving emails to other folders, sending email. Key to this is that office-js provides a method to get a token that can be used on these calls without needing any user interaction.

The Outlook REST API was deprecated in November 2020 and is set to be decommissioned in November 2022.

- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/outlook-rest-api-v2-0-deprecation-notice/

Microsoft suggests moving from the REST API to MS Graph API. This is fine for desktop, however the OfficeRuntime.Auth.getAccessToken method used to get the bootstrap token for MS Graph SSO access is only available in IdentityAPI 1.3 requirements set. The iOS and mobile platforms do not have IdentityAPI 1.3 available.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets

Does this effectively mean that there is no external Mail API access mechanism available to Outlook add-ins on mobile that doesn't require user interaction i.e. SSO on mobile is not possible for add-ins using MS Graph API.

Note: My main concern is around keeping the add-in working as it is on mobile, I'd hoped to do so using MS Graph but if that's not an option I'm open to alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Currently SSO is not supported on mobile. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](http://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered when we go through our planning process.